# Using tput with make

Tags: gnu-make, gnu, tput

I am looking to do some formatting of the output from my makefile using [tput](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termutils-2.0/html_chapter/tput_1.html). An example: if you simply type

```
echo $(printf '%*s' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' –)
```

as a command in your shell it will output a nice line spanning the entire width of your terminal window.

I am wondering if there's any way to carry this over in a makefile? The following only produces a blank line:

```
lineTest:
    @echo $$( printf '%*s' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' – )
```

Definitely a silly question, but please do chime in if you happen to know.

Comment: What shell are you running?

Comment: I currently use Z shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape ALL the `$` you want to pass to make.  You only escaped the first one.  Also I don't know why you're invoking printf in a subshell then echoing the results...??

This works for me:

```
lineTest:
        @printf '%*s\n' "$${COLUMNS:-$$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
```

I should point out, this won't work reliably if you invoke make with parallel builds enabled, because in parallel mode not all of the jobs get access to the terminal.

Comment: In makefiles I define the columns like this: ```# Define Terminal Info``` 
```COLUMNS   := $(shell tput cols)```